# Steps in creating xamarin cross platform mobile app (android, ios and windows)

Tags: xamarin.forms

i am using visual  studuio 2017
i would like to know what to select from the image below, which can allows me to create a cross platform mobile application for xamarin (android, ios, and windows)

I want to create a cross platform  mobile application enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Comment: please read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/

Comment: i later found out that my visual studio needs update so that i can select .net standard i for the code sharing. i later use vs2019. But if you are using vs2017 you can update it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should select `Cross Platform App(Xamarin)` to create xamarin cross platform mobile app.

Follow the [Xamarin.Forms Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/) to [build your first app.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/first-app/?pivots=windows)

You can update your Visual Studio 2017 to the lastest version, in the latest version, choose `Create new project` ==> `Visual C#` ==> `Cross-Platform` ==> **Mobile App(Xamarin.forms)**.

The `Class library(Xamarin forms)` you selected in the picture is a `Portable Class Library (PCL)`, you can have a look at this document about PCL: [what-is-a-portable-class-library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/pcl?tabs=windows#what-is-a-portable-class-library)